# How to get libgdx view from andengine project

Tags: android, libgdx, andengine

I want to initialize libgdx view from andengine project and add this view to the layout, which contains andengine view.

How can I initialize libgdx view from andengine project?

AndengineMainActivity extends BaseGameActivity and LibgdxMainActivity extends AndroidApplication.

Comment: Interesting question. I do not know the answer, but why would you even do such a thing? I am genuinely interested about what aspects of both engines you want to combine, since AndEngine and libgdx are competing in the same field.

Comment: Im working at gamedev company. Im developing games + creating various modules, such as promo module, ads module and so on. Our company use Andengine for small 2d games, but I am the one programer who use libgdx... So, Im working now on some module which needs various graphics effects and physics, and there is a big question for me: "how to use it with andengine projects" =))

Comment: If you want to use libgdx just because you aren't familiar with AndEngine, I think it may be easier to learn to use AndEngine, at least the physics part is basically the same. If I understood correctly, you want to have AndEngine and libgdx modules shown up on the screen at the same time, yes? I know there is a way to merge AndEngine view with native Android elements, so I guess integrating libgdx view should be possible. Look at the official AndEngine forums. Initializing the view should be easy, just use the standard way inside of AndEngine code. Integrating them might turn out to be a PITA.

Comment: Thx a lot. I decided to use andengine for this task too.

Comment: There may be another reason for mixing andEngine with libgdx: adding libgdx 3D support to AndEngine.